# Unable to run CheckSum Verification

Tags: java, checksum

I am trying to generate a checksum, but whenever I try running the Java code, it prints some errors before terminating. Here is my code:

ServerApplication.java

```
package com.snhu.sslserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;


@SpringBootApplication
public class ServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
class ServerController {

//FIXME:  Add hash function to return the checksum value for the data string that should 
contain your name.    
@RequestMapping("/hash")
public String myHash() {
    MessageDigest messageDigest = null; // Create an object of MessageDigest class
    String data = "Vincent Garza";
    String checkSum = null;
    try {
        // Initialize MessageDigest object with SHA-256 
        messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Use the digest() method of the class to generate a hash value of byte type from the unique data string
    messageDigest.update(data.getBytes()); // pass data to messageDigest
    byte[] digest = messageDigest.digest(); // compute messageDigest
    checkSum = this.bytesToHex(digest); // create hash value
   
    // return formatted string
    return "<p>data:"+data+"<br>name of the algorithm cipher used: SHA-256" + " <br>Checksum hash value: "+checkSum+ "</p>";
    }

    // Converts a byte array to a hexadecimal string
    public String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
       StringBuilder springBuilder = new StringBuilder();
       // loop through byte array
       for (byte hashByte : bytes) {
           int intVal = 0xff & hashByte;
           if (intVal < 0x10) {
               springBuilder.append('0');   // append elements
           }
           springBuilder.append(Integer.toHexString(intVal));
        }
        return springBuilder.toString();        // return hexadecimal string
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.snhu</groupId>
<artifactId>ssl-server</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ssl-server</name>
<description>ssl-server skeleton for CS-305</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

Errors in Console

```
          .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.4.RELEASE)

    2022-07-28 15:54:22.783  INFO 24856 --- [           main] 
    com.snhu.sslserver.ServerApplication     : Starting ServerApplication on MSI with PID 
    24856 (started by marce in C:\Users\marce\Downloads\CS 305 Module Five Checksum 
    Verification Assignment Code\module5_skel_student)
2022-07-28 15:54:22.786  INFO 24856 --- [           main] com.snhu.sslserver.ServerApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-07-28 15:54:23.884  INFO 24856 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8443 (https)
2022-07-28 15:54:23.892  INFO 24856 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-07-28 15:54:23.892  INFO 24856 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
2022-07-28 15:54:23.985  INFO 24856 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-07-28 15:54:23.985  INFO 24856 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1160 ms
2022-07-28 15:54:24.502  INFO 24856 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2022-07-28 15:54:24.905  INFO 24856 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-07-28 15:54:24.911  INFO 24856 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-07-28 15:54:24.914 ERROR 24856 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:297) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.snhu.sslserver.ServerApplication.main(ServerApplication.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:278) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197) ~[spring-boot-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1008) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: C:\Users\marce\Downloads\CS 305 Module Five Checksum Verification Assignment Code\module5_skel_student\keystore.p12 (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:217) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:586) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1005) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\marce\Downloads\CS 305 Module Five Checksum Verification Assignment Code\module5_skel_student\keystore.p12 (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:211) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:153) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:108) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:86) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:189) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.CatalinaBaseConfigurationSource.getResource(CatalinaBaseConfigurationSource.java:116) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:283) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:247) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]
    ... 20 common frames omitted

2022-07-28 15:54:24.917  INFO 24856 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

Can someone help me with this? I have tried fixing the problem involving TomCat but the solutions I get are to replace the port number with something else. But I don't see a port number in my code.

Comment: Did you investigate the final "caused by..." in your stack trace? `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\marce\Downloads\CS 305 Module Five Checksum Verification Assignment Code\module5_skel_student\keystore.p12 (The system cannot find the file specified)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your server is failing to init the ssl layer because its lacking "keystore.p12" file. generate/obtain this file and put it in the relevant location (which is probably C:\Users\marce\Downloads\CS 305 Module Five Checksum Verification Assignment Code\module5_skel_student\ ) then proceed again. you can also disable SSL altogether.